# Can i use INNER JOIN and IN command in one mysql query?

Tags: mysql

i try to connect two tables with one query. My first is cards and there are single values. Each card has its card_id, and in other table 'decks', where in column cards i have collection of card_id (for example : 21,23,1,23)
I want to get all cards in this collection with one query, and the query is :

```
SELECT *
FROM cards
INNER JOIN decks
ON cards.card_id IN decks.cards;
```

Can i do it like that? Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This makes no sense. JOIN joins separate records, so `decks.cards` is one separate scalar value, and `=` is more applicable then IN which is oriented on valueset.

Answer (score 1):

If `decks.cards` is a comma separated list then use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT *
FROM cards
INNER JOIN decks
ON FIND_IN_SET(cards.card_id, decks.cards);
```